# Giving text to the legend of a ggplot2 map, for geom_point with 2 different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to examine the residuals of my model on a map, using ggplot.

My data looks something like this below.

```
              LAT      LONG  residuals prevSampling
      2668 42.92890 -73.96417 -0.9456018           no
      2653 43.06538 -77.03785 -0.9178303          yes
      2579 42.45123 -78.86276 -0.9032406           no
      2654 42.88848 -78.64891 -0.8738269          yes
      2652 43.01445 -78.48273 -0.8539124          yes
      2510 42.51378 -78.04134 -0.8493541          yes
```

I'm first trying to plot the points by Lat/Long. I wanted the size of each point to correspond to the magnitude of the residuals and two different colors, for "yes" and "no" in prevSampling (i.e. size of points will vary for "yes" in one color / size of points will vary for "no" in another color).

I first created a base map with this code:

```
 gg1<-ny_base + 
theme_nothing() + 
geom_polygon(data = ny_county, fill = NA, color = "white") + 
geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)
```

And then tried to make a plot with this code. I split my data (res2017_occur_loc) into two dataframes (res2017_occur_locY & res2017_occur_locN), by whether the prevSampling is "yes" or "no".

```
 gg1 + 
geom_point(data = res2017_occur_locY, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT, size=res2017_occur_locY$residuals,color = "black", fill = "yellow",), shape = 21, group=FALSE) + 
geom_point(data = res2017_occur_locN, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT,size=res2017_occur_locN$residuals,color="black",fill="red"), shape = 21, group=FALSE) + 
theme(legend.position = c(0, 1),legend.justification = c(0, 1))+
scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow","red"))
```

I've posted the top of the map to show the issues I'm having.

It gives me a map with different size points of different colors but
(1) the legend doesn't have any text next to the legend / I can't figure out how to label it
(2) is there away to get an idea of the magnitude of the residuals in the legend?

Thank you so much in advance!

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Doesn't `theme_nothing()` default to having no legend at all?  Have you tried using `legend = TRUE` in `theme_nothing()`?

Comment: I just saw this comment after trying the others. @aosmith--yes this works! It doesn't create as nice of a legend, e.g. it lumps the colors together versus a legend with yes and no. Thanks--each comment is helping me learn more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split things up like that. You can specify what to use as a shape, and what to use for a fill. If `prevSampling` is a factor, you can just wrap it in `factor` within the `aes`, otherwise it doesn't need it (like `fill = factor(prevSampling)`). If you want the sizes larger for smaller numbers, i.e. larger for -0.9, just add `scale_size(trans = "reverse)` to the end.

```
df <- structure(list(LAT = c(42.9289, 43.06538, 42.45123, 42.88848, 
43.01445, 42.51378, 43.31254, 42.4399), LONG = c(-73.96417, -77.03785, 
-78.86276, -78.64891, -78.48273, -78.04134, -78.3917, -78.0129
), residuals = c(-0.9456018, -0.9178303, -0.9032406, -0.8738269, 
-0.8539124, -0.8493541, -0.3224, -0.2934), prevSampling = c("no", 
"yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

library(maps)
usa <- map_data("state")
ny <- subset(usa, region %in% "new york")

p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = ny, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = "white", fill = "grey10")

p +
 geom_point(data = df, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT, size = residuals, fill = prevSampling), shape = 21, group=FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0, 1), legend.justification = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(size = "Residuals", fill = "Previous Sampling")
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried both codes and I was able to get the map that I wanted w/ @Anonymous coward code (ha).  I think my base map (my gg1 is the problem as after I made prevSampling into a factor and used p map below, I got the legend/image I wanted. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Following up @Anonymous coward, when I wrote my code, I filled in `ggplot(....)` whereas the p code above wrote it as `ggplot()+geom_polygon`....could someone shed insight on why this would cause such a difference in the plot/legend? Thanks!                                                                                              
 `ny_base <- ggplot(data = NY, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
ny_base + theme_nothing()`

Comment: My residuals actually run from -.9 to .9 and this code  only gives me three sizes (-.5, 0, .5). Is there a way have a greater variation in size, similar to the figure above? Thanks!

Comment: You could put the map data in that first `ggplot(ny)` followed by your `geom` call, as long as other `geoms` specify what data to use if it's different. It is the `theme_nothing()` that erased all of that. I didn't realize you were using `ggmap`. In the future, it's helpful to put what libraries you are using in your question. Without seeing your data, it's impossible to reproduce, but you can manually set a range within `scale_size(range = c(-0.9, 0.9))`. It should scale itself to your min/max by itself though.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not split out your data, since ggplot can work with it as factor, chase do:

```
res2017_occur_loc$prevSampling <- as.factor(res2017_occur_loc$prevSampling)
```

Then change your plot code:

```
gg1 + geom_point(data = res2017_occur_loc, aes(x = LONG, y = LAT, size=res2017_occur_loc$residuals,colour = res2017_occur_loc$prevSampling), shape = 21, group=FALSE)+ scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow","red")) + theme(legend.position = c(0, 1),legend.justification = c(0, 1)) + labs( colour = 'Prev. Sampling', size= 'Residuals')
```

This should work. For discrete colors you should use factor variables, and not split the data.
I hope that it work for you and help.